# Express.js | Node.js - Can I use a resource in a different resource?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I have two "get" resources in my node.js/express.js program, can I use the first resource in the second resource?

Example:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.get('/resource1', function (req, res) {
    res.send("Hello");
}

app.get('/resource2', function (req, res) {

    // Can I use the response from resource1 here?

}
```

If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do 2 things:

1. you can make an http request from resource2 to resource1 and get the response from there.
2. The better solution in my eyes is to put resource1 logics in a "Business logics" function and call this function from the resource2 endpoint.

You can also call the actual request function of resource1 if you re-write the code to:

```
app.get('/resource1', resource1Func);

function resource1Func(req, res)
{
    res.send("Hello");
}

app.get('/resource2', function (req, res) {
    resource1Func(res, res);
    //some other logics
}
```

Comment: But when I call the function in resource2, I cant do some other logics after that, because headers are send already. Because the resource1 function sends the text.

Comment: That is correct, therefore my suggestion number 2 is probably the best solution for you. can you elaborate on what exactly are you trying to achive?

Comment: I have two resources. Books and libraries. One resource give me all libraries and one gives me a book by id. The books are json strings and they contain the ID's of all libraries where the book is available. Now I want to expand the "give me all libraries resource" with "give me all libraries that hold a particular book". And for that I want to use the "give me a book by id resource". When I get the IDs of the libraries that hold the book, I can filter them in the "give me all libraries resource".

Comment: So in that case, you can create a function which called getBookById which the Books resource should call to and it will perform all the logics without the express objects('req', 'res'). then you can call this function from the Libraries resource without setting headers and responding anything to the client until all the "give me all libraries that hold a particular book" request logics has finished